# C++, can't access included header files from so library

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, shared-libraries

I try to include my self built .so library in the `test.cpp` file.
When I try to make the test.cpp file I get this exception:

```
root@airdrop:/home/pi/naza-interface/examples# make
g++ -c test.cpp
test.cpp:31:35: fatal error: naza_interface_manual.h: No such file or 
directory
#include "naza_interface_manual.h"
                               ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'test.o' failed
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

The Makefile for test.cpp looks like that:

```
output: test.o
            g++ -L. -lnazainterface -o test test.o

test.o:
            g++ -c test.cpp

clean:
            rm -f *.o
```

test.cpp just includes the library.

```
#include "naza_interface_manual.h"
```

The library contains two files, `naza_interface_manual.h` and `naza_interface_manual.cpp`. The library's makefile looks like that:

```
libso: naza_interface_manual.o pca9685.o
            g++ -fPIC -L/usr/local/lib -shared naza_interface_manual.o 
            pca9685.o -lbcm2835 -o libnazainterface.so

naza_interface_manual.o: src/naza_interface_manual.cpp src/naza_interface_manual.h
            g++ -fPIC -c -Wall src/naza_interface_manual.cpp

pca9685.o: src/PCA9685/pca9685.cpp src/PCA9685/pca9685.h
            g++ -c src/PCA9685/pca9685.cpp

install: naza_interface_manual.o pca9685.o
            g++ -L/usr/local/lib naza_interface_manual.o pca9685.o -lbcm2835 - 
shared -o /usr/local/libnazainterface.so

clean:
            rm *.o output
```

naza_interface_manual.h:

```
#ifndef NAZA_INTERFACE_MANUAL_H_
#define NAZA_INTERFACE_MANUAL_H_


class naza_interface_manual_c{
    public:
            naza_interface_manual_c();

            // A: For roll control (left/right)
            // E: For pitch control (front/back)
            // T: For throttle control
            // R: For rudder control
            // U: For Control Model Switch
            void configure_pins(int A, int E, int T, int R, int U);

            void fly_forward(int speed);
            void fly_backward(int speed);
            void fly_up(int speed);
            void fly_down(int speed);
            void fly_left(int speed);
            void fly_right(int speed);

 };


 #endif
```

naza_interface_manual.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "naza_interface_manual.h"
#include "PCA9685/pca9685.h"

naza_interface_manual_c::naza_interface_manual_c(){

    std::cout << "Starting Naza Interface";

}

void naza_interface_manual_c::configure_pins(int A, int E, int T, int R, int U){
    PCA9685 pca9685;

    pca9685.SetFrequency(100);

    pca9685.Write(CHANNEL(0), VALUE(350));
}
void naza_interface_manual_c::fly_forward(int speed){

}
void naza_interface_manual_c::fly_backward(int speed){

}
void naza_interface_manual_c::fly_up(int speed){

}
void naza_interface_manual_c::fly_down(int speed){

}
void naza_interface_manual_c::fly_left(int speed){

}
void naza_interface_manual_c::fly_right(int speed){

}
```

Comment: A header file is not a library. Very unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: You should probably study some more about how C++ headers work. It’s a very primitive mechanism, dating from the late 1960s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compilation doesn't give the compiler the include path to find the header.

Instead, specify a base location and add the path to the compile.  Otherwise if you can change the naza interface library, its `install` target should install the headers to a system (or `$PREFIX/include`) location.

```
test.o:
            g++ -I$(NAZA_INTERFACE_LIB)/src/ -c test.cpp
```

Comment: My makefile looks now like that: https://pastebin.com/FzbcqN3R I added the header files path to .o files but does still not work :/

Comment: Go ahead and ask a new SO question regarding the new failure.

Answer (score 3):

Your Makefile doesn't install the header file. In fact, it also installs the shared object in a non-standard location: `/usr/local`. You want the library to go into `/usr/local/lib` and you need the header file installed in `/usr/local/include`.

Your Makefile is not consistent with conventional rules: You have no `all` rule, you are *creating* the library directly in the installation directory, instead of calling /usr/bin/install... I suggest you look into "proper" Makefile layout, if you want to distribute this. Users expect a lot of things from the Makefiles you give them; there are de-facto standards to follow.

If you want to use the library *without* having installed it, you need to provide the compiler the relevant include directive in your `test.o:` target; something like `-Ipath/to/your/header`.

Comment: Can you give me a link for a proper .so make library template? thx in advance

Comment: Try a google search... I just did and found several that seem nice, though none of them include an `install` target. That's a different search away, though. Really, if you want to use Makefiles on linux/bsd, I would suggest to jump on the AutoMake wagon. It'll handle all the boiler-plate for you. John Calcote wrote a nice book on the subject, which even starts with basic Makefile stuff, but obviously that's not a free solution. If you put in the effort, google can "teach" you a lot, though, and that's free.